# How to configure rubymine for use with open3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, popen3, xray-rails

**Issue**

I am using [xray-rails gem](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails#current-support) in a rails app and want it to open rubymine to the correct file when I click it in the browser.  It was unclear how to configure this.  xray-rails gem uses open3 to open the file in the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Prerequisite:  Follow the instructions for setting up rubymine to be callable from the commandline found in [Running RubyMine as a Diff or Merge Command Line Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.2/running-rubymine-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html)

*NOTE: This is also a handy use of rubymine, allowing it to perform diffs between files.  Nice bonus for researching a solution to my problem.*

Create ~/.xrayconfig with content...

```
:editor: mine
```

*NOTE: **mine** is the name of the script created in the prerequisite steps.  If you named your script something different, use that name in place of **mine**.*

Now when you start xray-rails in your browser and click, the corresponding file will open in rubymine.